# How to program a daily task with Python & Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, datetime

I have to run a daily web search with selenium, so I made a Selenium function and put it in a infinite while loop using the time module:

```
while True:
    selenium_function()
    time.sleep(86400)
```

Is this the right way to do it? Or should I use instead an inner Selenium option ?

**EDIT**

I found (while looking for cron on YouTube...) this [Python module scheduler](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/), so my code is now like that:

```
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(selenium_function)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Do you have any experience with this way?

Comment: If you need to run this daily then 3600 seconds won't help you at all.  That will run every hour.  It also assumes your computer will be on and active 24 hours a day.  It would be better to look into a scheduler for this, batch script etc

Comment: You would normally use `cron` rather than rely on `sleep`

Comment: @JD2775 yes indeed, 3600 was for test, 24*3600 is the right value. Is there a python module you have in mind for such scheduler ?

Comment: @roganjosh ok, I'll look into `cron`

Comment: I am not well versed in this area but I don't think it's a Python module you are looking for.  You want some way to execute your `.py` script from outside of it, on a schedule.  Google `cron` or `batch file` or `shell script` something along those lines

Comment: If you genuinely need Selenium then running it from `cron` is slightly challenging because you need to set up a separate headless X11 server where you can run the browser without interfering with a logged-in regular user GUI session. If you can use a simpler scraping tool like `requests`, running from `cron` will be much less complex.

Comment: @tripleee I see... It is part of a Python program, so it would be nice to stay inside this scope... Do you think anyway that the time.sleep() function may crash by itself before 1 or 2 days ?

Comment: `requests` is a Python module, `cron` persists across reboots etc.

Comment: @tripleee Ok, thank you, I see the point.